# fabric can't detect multiple ssh keys on remote

Tags: python, git, ssh, fabric

It's all right to ssh to git from remote terminal.
But got password required while using fabric command at local.

After I check fablog I found these:

```
DEB [20150804-15:13:13.251] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20150804-15:13:13.279] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key a0329c4d2669f3c5ab5651cef4f41eda in /Users/howie/.ssh/id_rsa
DEB [20150804-15:13:13.293] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20150804-15:13:14.509] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEB [20150804-15:13:14.524] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key cff84423999b0044447c1334af27ca91 in /Users/howie/.ssh/id_dsa
DEB [20150804-15:13:14.528] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20150804-15:13:14.537] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

Seems fabric try to use default id_rsa to connect to git,but the right file was named as id_rsa_osc because I got multiple git environment.

How can I configure fabric to connect to git with custom ssh file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to overcome this issue is to use the `ssh-agent` program to hold your keys. Then you can `ssh-add` the keys you want before running `fabric`. Ideally you should set this up so that the agent runs automatically when you log in, though some environments don't make that easy.

If you haven't used `ssh-agent` before, [this tutorial](http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent) should help. If you have, sorry for including unhelpful information.

Comment: It works.I'm not sure this problem caused by multiple ssh keys now because I got almost similarly log after a success remote-git ssh.Then I realized that log recored my local operation, not remote.